# How would you make this Python Dictionary thread-safe?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a Web Server running in `Python`. The server is private, so i only expect around 20 users to connect to it. The server is multi-threaded (8 cores at the moment, so 8 threads I guessed).

When requests come in, I am able to identify the users. On some queries, I need to update a simple `dictionary` of the form  **username -> Boolean**. How could I make this one thread safe ?

Comment: Are you implementing the server yourself or are you using something like django, pyramid or twisted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need a lock (to avoid the race conditions Joonas described), and are stuck with Python 2.4,

```
import threading
lock = threading.Lock()

shared_dict = {}

def do_thing(user, value):
    lock.acquire()
    try:
        shared_dict[user] = value
    finally:
        # Always called, even if exception is raised in try block
        lock.release()
```

Comment: let's say my writer wraps its modifications under that lock. Will the reader wait until this is released, i.e. writing has finished ? Or do I need to wrap the reads in that as well ?

Comment: @jeromeG you'd probably need to have a similar locked function for reading (again just to avoid the "read-modify-write" race conditions)

Answer (score 17):

You'll need to create a global lock object.

```
lock = threading.Lock()
```

Then around each access of the dictionary acquire and release the lock. The simplest way to do this is with the new(ish) [`with` syntax](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111211102/http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

```
with lock:
    dict[key] = value
```

Comment: i am restricted to the use of Python 2.4, would that be not available I guess ?

Comment: No, the with is not available, but you can use lock.acquire() and lock.release instead().

Answer (score 11):

You may or may not need to use a lock, depending on how the `Boolean` is updated.

If the value of the `Boolean` *doesn't* depend on its previous value, then no lock is needed: writing and reading a Python dictionary is thread-safe by itself (except: [writing while iterating is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358770/python-dictionary-is-thread-safe) - but that's not allowed in single thread either). The memory visibility is similar to what would be achieved using `volatile` in some languages.

What's inherently not thread-safe is the "read-modify-write" -sequence, resulting in a race condition. If the value of the `Boolean` *does* depend on its previous value, then  you have to use a lock, because otherwise thread A could first read the value, then thread B could change it, and then A would change it again, based on outdated value to start with.

Answer (score 2):

Use [threading.LOCK.acquire()](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#lock-objects) before updating the dictionary and use threading.LOCK.release(), once you are done updating it.

Comment: This is strange, I would have expected the lock object to be specific to the dictionary, a little like a synchronized object/block/method in Java... I'm confused

Answer (score -1):

You don´t need to lock dictionary to this operation, because this operation is atomic, and GIL take care this for you. Unless you have operations like read-change-write, don't worry.