# Python dictionary needs synchronization?

Tags: python, dictionary, synchronization, thread-safety

If a have a Python dictionary and have multiple threads adding to it, do I have to 
synchronize the addition of elements if I know that every thread is going to add to its own key. ( What I mean is that no addition for the same key can take place at the same time ).

Comment: possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358770/python-dictionary-is-thread-safe

Comment: I do not think it is a duplicate.

Comment: You're right. But it is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953351/thread-safety-in-pythons-dictionary

Comment: @shx2: It's just similar. In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953351/thread-safety-in-pythons-dictionary, the dictionary structure is static (no new keys added in threads), so the access is usually safe (in the end, just a single pointer reference is updated). Here, the structure of the dict changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to synchronize access to a dictionary object when your keys are not unique per thread. Access is not necessarily thread safe.

You can always use the [`dis` (disassembler) module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) to verify any python code; python thread context can switch between any opcode (opcodes themselves are executed atomically); access to a dict can be spread over several opcodes:

```
>>> def foo():
...     somedict = {}
...     somedict['bar'] = 'spam'
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 BUILD_MAP                0
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (somedict)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('spam')
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (somedict)
             12 LOAD_CONST               2 ('bar')
             15 STORE_SUBSCR        
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

There are 4 opcodes involved with the `somedict['bar'] = spam` line, loading the `somedict` reference, loading the `'bar'` and `'spam'` constants, and calling the store operation. Thread contexts can be switched between any of these opcodes.

That said, if your keys are guaranteed to be unique per thread, you could get away with not locking the structure; like all opcodes, the `STORE_SUBSCR` opcode is executed by the python interpreter under the GIL, so multiple threads storing in and reading information from *their own key* should be safe.

The Python standard library library does this in a few locations; using `thread.thread_ident()` as a dictionary key to store per-thread information in a dictionary. The [`threading` module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/threading.py) for example, keeps a `_active` module-global dictionary keyed on thread identifiers.

Comment: The `STORE_SUBSCR` opcode isn't necessarily atomic: if overwriting a key that already exists, and either the key or the value that is overwritten uses `__del__` (or has the last reference to something that does) you can get a thread switch when objects are released. In practice this isn't likely to be a problem, but it is worth remembering when you try to take advantage of the GIL to avoid explicit locking.